# I need to compare list with Datatable and filter values using Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, filter, datatable

I need to compare a list with Datatable column and return the result as the values from the list which are not present in DataTable.

List:
[image: List to compare]

DataTable:
[image: Datable to compare]

Here I need to compare the list with Datable User Id column and return the result from the list which is not present in DataTable.

For Example, 
IMS022 and IMS029 are present in List and not present in Datable.Hence I should get IMS022, IMS029 as filter result

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
var result = list.Except(dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["User Id"]));
```

You need to import `System.Linq` namespace to use `Except`.

Comment: No need to overrird the gethashfunction and Equals methods? I am having some extra values too filtered out with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=Items.Except(datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.UserID<string>(columnIndex)));
```

Hope it helps!